# Matplotlib saves pdf with data outside set

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot

I have a problem with Matplotlib. I usually make big plots with many data points and then, after zooming or setting limits, I save in pdf only a specific subset of the original plot. The problem comes when I open this file: matplotlib saves all the data into the pdf making not visible the one outside of the range. This makes almost impossible to open afterwards those plots or to import them into latex.

Any idea of how I could solve this problem is really welcome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Determine the range that you want to view and filter your data to remove the unwanted parts. How this is done depends on what you're plotting.

Comment: iirc this is something that has been fixed on master.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a requirement to use PDF figures, you can save the matplotlib figures as `.png`; this format just contains the data on the screen, e.g. I tried saving a large scatter plot as PDF, its size was `198M`; as png it came out as `270K`; plus I've never had any problems using png inside latex.

Comment: I'd love to have pdf, I can modify easier wrong labels and they look nicer in beamer. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested that this will work, but it might be worth rasterizing some of the artists:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(..., rasterized=True)
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=600)
```

which will rasterize the artist when saving to vector formats.  If you use a high enough dpi this should give you reasonable quality.